# How to pass data as context in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to pass the context in an Enzyme test using Jest, [as shown in the Airbnb doc](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setContext.html), but the context is returning `undefined`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component{
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log("Context in App", this.context) // getting undefined when running test case
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Sample Application
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

describe('App test cases', () => {
  let wrapper;
  let AppContext = {name: "React is Simple"};
   beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App />, {context: AppContext })
   })
   test('should pass render the component without crashing', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
   })
})
```

**Versions**

```
React: 16.8.1
enzyme: 3.8.0
enzyme-adapter-react-16: 1.7.1
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're supposed to have access to `this.context` before mounting?

Comment: you are asking put a console.log() before the componentWillMount

Comment: Maybe try replacing `componentWillMount` with `componentDidMount` to see if that is, in fact, the problem.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: You really shouldn't use `componentWillMount` as it's been deprecated due to several issues

Comment: tried using in componentDidMount not getting anything

Comment: @Isaac tried using componentDidMount but still this.context is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an [open issue for enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1973) for [the new context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). As a workaround you can set up static [`contextTypes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html):

```
App.contextTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Then you can manipulate the context as you wish:

```
shallow(<App />, {context: {name: "React is Simple"}}) // did mount
    .setContext({ name: 'some new context'}); // did update
```

And in your App:

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Context in App", this.context) 
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.context);
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: should i use setContext ? to get the context in componentDidMount. Also why i am not able to get the context in componentWillMount

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS included `setContext` just to show how component might reflect the context updates.  For the original case it seems to not required. `componentWillMount` should handle context as you expected (even though it's legacy), if you implement the answer.

Comment: should i need to add the App.contextTypes. So the new library of enzyme doesn't support the new way of passing context is that correct ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes, add `App.contextTypes`.

Comment: so in the app.contextType what ever you are passing that should be there this the only way that you can unit test. Still the library is working on it

Comment: if i have the context like name and id, then if i need both how should i pass that one. Since the contextTypes have some mapping to the context.

Comment: any idea on this how to pass multiple properties to the  object instead of a object having a single property

Comment: got it we need to add the properties each in the App.contextTypes cool :)

Comment: This is what I got, when I pass context like this: `Warning: ComponentName defines an invalid contextType. contextType should point to the Context object returned by React.c
reateContext(). Did you accidentally pass the Context.Provider instead?`