# Enzyme context doesn't passed

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-context

I tried to set context to component in `shallow` method, but when I log context after it return empty object.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component />, {context: {active: true, view: 'default'}})

console.log(wrapper.context()) / {}
```

When i tried to create wrapper with `mount` method, and then just log original context, it return default component context, but also, I can't change it with passing context to mount method or with `setContext()`.

What I did wrong, and how to pass context to component with Enzyme?

UPD:
This is how my component use context:

```
import { ViewModeContext } from '/ViewModeProvider'

class ComponentName extends Component {
   static contextType = ViewModeContext

   ...
}
```

Comment: perhaps the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293154/how-to-pass-data-as-context-in-jest/55298035#55298035

Comment: can you show how `Component` uses context?

Comment: @Alex added to my question

Comment: Shouldn't [it be](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) `contextTypes` (ending `s`)?

Comment: @Alex legit, but now i receive: ```Warning: ComponentName declares both contextTypes and contextType static properties. The legacy contextTypes property will be ignored.```

Answer (score 2):

Your codebase is correct. There are still no full support for the new react context api by `enzyme`. You can track the general status in section `New context APIs in 16.3` of [this issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1553), and especially status of [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/14329) which will add `contextType` support.